# R igraph make “subgraph” from igraph object from list of vertices, infer edges between selected vertices if there are connected nodes in original

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I am using igraph from R. I know we can make a subgraph with selected vertices but if those nodes aren’t directly connected, there won’t be an edge in the new subgraph. Is there a way to make a subgraph which creates an edge between two nodes if there are other nodes (that are not a part of the vertex list) indirectly connecting those two nodes?
For example, if I have a graph which has the following edges:
E-F
F-G
And my vertex list contains E and G, how can I create a new subgraph that creates that edge E-G?
Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct but what I've opted to do is create a distance matrix from and to my query vertices and convert this "weighted" adjacency matrix to an igraph object.      `1.  library(igraph)`
`q <- graph_from_literal(E--F, F--G)` 2. get distance:`query = distances(q,v = TFs,  to = TFs, weights =  E(q)$weight, algorithm = 'bellman-ford' )`
    
3. convert weighted adjacency to weighted igraph object: `graph_obj = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(query, weighted = TRUE, mode = 'directed' )` where the new edgeweight is the shortest distance between the two nodes`

Answer (score 3):

One way to find neighbors that are two steps away is to multiply the adjacency matrix with itself (see comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3641702/common-neighbour-matrix-of-a-graph) for example).

First create the graph described in the question:

```r
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_literal(E--F, F--G)
```

Then take the adjacency matrix (`m`) and multiply it with itself.

```r
m <- get.adjacency(g, sparse = F)
m2 <- m %*% m
```

Built new graph from resulting adjacency matrix and remove all vertices that have a degree of 0 (no second-degree neighbor):

```r
g2 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m2, diag = F, mode = "undirected") 
induced_subgraph(g2, degree(g2) > 0)
#> IGRAPH 089bf67 UN-- 2 1 -- 
#> + attr: name (v/c)
#> + edge from 089bf67 (vertex names):
#> [1] E--G
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This would be limited to 2 hop neighbors, correct? What if the nodes are far away e.g. 100 nodes away but still have "in-between" nodes connecting them?

Comment: @Ben Instead of converting to/from an adjancey matrix, you can use `connect(g, 2)` to connect to 2nd order neighbours. This will also keep 1st order connection.

Comment: @EuniceChoi So you just want to connect vertices within the same (weakly) connected component? Use `components()` and connect vertices that have the same component index.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon the suggestions in the comments, I arrive at:

```
require(igraph)
set.seed(1)    
g   <- erdos.renyi.game(2^6, 1/32)
V(g)$name <- seq(vcount(g))
filter <- c(7,22, 1, 4, 6)
amg <- g[]                                  # adjacency matrix g
clg <- clusters(g)$membership               # strongly connected components

amtc      <- clg[row(amg)] == clg[col(amg)] # adjacency matrix of transitive closure
dim(amtc) <- dim(amg)
gtc <- simplify(graph.adjacency(amtc, mode="undirected")) # transitive closure of g
V(gtc)$name <- V(g)$name

isg <- induced_subgraph(gtc, filter)
plot(isg)
```

However this solution is not feasible if g is large and the subgraph significantly smaller.

Answer (score 1):

If subgraph << original graph then:

```
require(igraph)
set.seed(1)    
g   <- erdos.renyi.game(2^6, 1/32)
V(g)$name <- seq(vcount(g))
filter <- c(1, 4, 6, 7, 22, 25)

stopifnot(!is.directed(g))                 # assume undirected graph
mscc  <- components(g)$membership[filter]  # membership strongly connected components
amfi <- outer(X=mscc, mscc, FUN = "==")*1  # cross product = 1, when equal
fitc <- simplify(graph.adjacency(amfi, mode="undirected")) # transitive closure of filter in g
plot(fitc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Szabolcs, note that connect(g, vcount(g)) computes the transitive closure of g. However not suitable for larger graphs (vcount > 8192).

```
require(igraph)
g  <- make_graph(~ E-G, G-F)
fi <- c("E", "F")

system.time(tcg <- connect(g, vcount(g)) )
sg <- subgraph(tcg, V(tcg)[fi])
sg
```